# convert weblogic admin server into managed server

Tags: java, weblogic

I'm currently having 2 Weblogic admin servers in 2 different domains created on the same machine.
I want to convert one of the admin server to a managed server and then use them together to deploy a Java application. Is this feasible? If yes, how?

I'm currently using Weblogic Server 10.3.

PS: I'm quite new to Weblogic domain creation and administration. Please revert for any more details needed.

Comment: Add a new server to one of your domains, deploy the application, and shut down the admin server you are no longer using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no, however, adding a managed server to a domain is extremely simple.  See the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/domainconfig/CreateManagedServers.html).  When deploying your application you'll need to target both servers or create a cluster (also [very easy](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/clusters/CreateCluster.html)), add both machines to it and give the cluster name as the target.

Note, it is generally not concidered best practice to target applications to the Admin server (although it's fine when you're developing on your local machine).  If you have the resources available on your environment, you could create two managed servers and put them in a cluster.  Depending on the configuration of your Admin server, you may be able to reduce it's size if memory is tight.